# My method to load the html from a url in a web browser does not work

Tags: java, browser

I am trying to make a web browser for the fun of it, i seem to get errors when ever i put in my `loadHtml` method, when i comment that out everything works even the action listener.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class browserPannel extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        JFrame browser = new JFrame("A Nun In A Weelchair");
        browser.setSize(1000,700);
        browser.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        browser.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel header = new JPanel();
        header.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        JTextField url = new JTextField(20);
        url.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    //loadHtml(event.getActionCommand);
                    System.out.println("action performed");
                }
            }
            );
        url.setSize(890,30);
        url.setVisible(true);

        JButton send = new JButton("Send");
        send.setSize(75,30);
        send.setVisible(true);

        JEditorPane htmlc = new JEditorPane();
        htmlc.setBackground(Color.red);
        htmlc.setEditable(true);
        htmlc.setContentType("text/html");


        header.add(url, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        header.add(send);
        browser.getContentPane().add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        browser.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(htmlc));


        browser.pack();
        browser.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void loadHtml(String link)
    {
        try{
            //htmlc.setPage(link);
            //url.setText(link);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("ops sorry could not fined Virgine Mobile");
        }
    }

}
```

from what i can tell it looks like it can not recognize the `url` and the `htmlc`

I have tried to comment the `htmlc.setPage` and the `url.setText`, and when i do that my program compiles.
why am i getting these errors, shouldn't it recognize that they are defined above?

Comment: Whats the exception stack trace?

Comment: if the url is an invaled url then it displays whats under the `catch` or else the program crashes

Comment: Neither the variables htmlc or url are defined within the scope of your loadHtml() method. That is why you're seeing errors when compiling the code. They are only currently defined within the main() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method isn't `static` but you're trying to call it from a `static` context (`main()`) Also, your instances in the `main()` method aren't visible in the `loadHtml()` method. You could pass them into the method (or declare them as `static` fields in your class). Finally, you shouldn't swallow `Exception` (at least `printStackTrace()`). So I think you were looking for something like,

```
private static void loadHtml(JEditorPane htmlc, JTextField url, String link) {
    try{
        htmlc.setPage(link);
        url.setText(link);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ops sorry could not find Virgin Mobile");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, `loadHtml(event.getActionCommand);` isn't correct. You'd need parenthesis to call your original method `loadHtml(event.getActionCommand());`, but with the above changes it would be `loadHtml(htmlc, url, event.getActionCommand());` (and to use the `htmlc` and `url` references in your inner class you must declare those references as `final`. For example, `final JTextField url = new JTextField(20);`).

*Alternatively*, you could make the components `static` so they're *shared* across all instances (and methods - first comment them out in your `main` method) -

```
private static final JTextField url = new JTextField(20);
private static final JEditorPane htmlc = new JEditorPane();
private static void loadHtml(String link) {
    try{
        htmlc.setPage(link);
        url.setText(link);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ops sorry could not find Virgin Mobile");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to use `loadHtml(event.getActionCommand())`

Comment: Won't work either. htmlc and url aren't fields. They are local to the main method.

Comment: The fact that someone down voted this is outrageous.

Comment: @Julien When I said "or declare them as `static` fields", I did not say they are currently fields. In fact, I meant rather the opposite. I think you'll find that *your instances in the `main()` method aren't visible in the `loadHtml()` method* is the problem I identified.

Comment: i had the `loadHtml(event.getActionCommand);` under the `actionListener` commented out for working with one error at a time, when i un comment it it tells me it cannot fined the variable `getActionCommand` and it also tells me that it cannot implement `actionPerformed`

Comment: @yoseph1998 `loadHtml(htmlc, url, event.getActionCommand());`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yep, I saw that you identified the problem clearly.

Comment: when i do that it tells me that the `htmlc` and the `url` are part of the inner class, and it should be declared final?? i am not sure what it means by declared final? (also why do i have to define that inside the htmlc when it is already defined in the class)

Comment: @yoseph1998 To share the variables with your inner class they have to be declared constant references. `final JTextField url = new JTextField(20);`, I've edited my answer. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @yoseph1998 You defined the variables in the scope of a method (not class). They have method local scope. You can move them to be class fields (`static`) or you can add them to the method signature or you can access them with an inner class (if they're `final`).

Comment: if i where to move everything into another main method, and leave the action listener where it is, rename the current main method to just a loader method that is not a static(because the actionPerformed cannot be a static method), in order to be able to define url in the loader method is stating it in the loader method all i have to do? `public void loader(JFrame browser, JTextField url, JEditorPane htmlc, JPanel header, JButton send, String[] arg)`

Comment: @yoseph1998 Try it. If you're still confused post another question.